# How can I make the titlebar look like what shows in Visual Studio 2013 Using C# & XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, titlebar

In Visual Studio 2013 when you're developing your WPF C# XAML application in Design mode it shows a window with a much nicer title bar style;however, when you build your application the titlebar looks much different and less stylish. Here's an example of what an looks like in the designer:

[image: VS2013 Designer Title]

and here's what it actually looks like when you build:

[image: VS2013 Compiled Title Bar]

How can I make it look like what it shows in the designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the window is using your OS's theme. To change that you have many options. But, I would recommend you using [Mahapps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/) library. It's nice, easy to use, and customizable.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because as soon as I included this in my project it instantly transformed all of the elements of my GUI to look very nice and even added some nice subtle animation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the power of WPF with styling. Here's some examples:

[Modern UI for WPF](https://mui.codeplex.com/)

[image]

[Visual Studio 2012 Metro Styles for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442856/Visual-Studio-Metro-Styles-for-WPF)

[image]

Comment: Those are nice but I'm not trying to create app store/metro apps. I'm making this app for the normal desktop.

Comment: The projects above **are** styles for desktop WPF applications.  WPF can **only** be used to create "desktop" applications.

Comment: There is no such thing as an App Store app built with WPF; all WPF apps, including the ones demoed on that site, are desktop apps.  App Store apps are built with an entirely different framework from WPF, though it is similar in some respects (e.g., they both use Xaml).

Comment: oh okay. it just looked like it in the second example but https://mui.codeplex.com/ looks nice. So does the other suggestion of mahapps.metro looks nice too. Have you tried that one?